# What is the object that holds Email Alerts?

Tags: email-alert

We changed company name.  I want to update the company-wide email address.  Even in Dataloader it does not allow an update because the email is used in email alerts.  I want to update the From email on all of the email alerts through Dataloader.
What is the object that holds the email alerts?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access this via the Data Loader. It's called the WorkflowAlert, part of the [Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm) metadata object. You can access this via [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) or a Salesforce IDE that supports this object, such as IlluminatedCloud, VS Code, etc. You'll want to read the documentation if you're interested in learning more, but the point is, there's no "data loader" type method provided by Salesforce to mass update these entries.

Comment: N.B. Intellij's Salesforce IDE is called IlluminatedCloud

Comment: @cropredy Thanks. I knew it was something like that, but it's been a while.